# Duplicate SSIS Column Headers

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am taking a view in a SQL DB and placing it into a CSV file using SSIS. Before doing so, I convert everything to unicode, which gives me two of everything. I was not having this issue until I recently made the change to append a date to the end of my output file by using an expression. I am receiving duplicate rows and everything is just pasted accross twice. Any suggestions to only get them to come out once on the CSV? Image below.

[image: SSIS duplicate rows]

[image: The Inputs are not mapped]

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured it out. When I changed my connection string to my flat file to be a function, it reset my columns to have duplicate columns. I just had to go into my connection manager for the flat file and delete the extra columns.